# Compile test case using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I am developing a tool to automate the launch of test cases in existing projects. I tried to run the tool on the "dropwizard" project (https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard, SHA: c4b3ad27349c6a26dc3e0d3c89a119617af3f7bb) currently the tool executes the steps:

1. download the project
2. enter the direcotry src and paste the jars file of junit4 and hamcrest-core.jar
   3)the tool is placed in the src directory
3. reads the test case to be performed (in the specific case testGracefulShutdown) through the command:

   `javac -cp junit4.jar:. dropwizard-core/src/test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java`

but he keeps giving me this errors:

```
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:3: error: package org.fest.assertions.api does not exist
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
                                     ^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:4: error: package io.dropwizard.configuration does not exist
import io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationFactory;
                                  ^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:5: error: package io.dropwizard.jackson does not exist
import io.dropwizard.jackson.DiscoverableSubtypeResolver;
                            ^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:6: error: package io.dropwizard.jackson does not exist
import io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson;
                            ^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:7: error: package io.dropwizard.jetty does not exist
import io.dropwizard.jetty.HttpConnectorFactory;
                          ^
./test/java/io/dropwizard/server/DefaultServerFactoryTest.java:8: error: package io.dropwizard.logging does not exist
import io.dropwizard.logging.ConsoleAppenderFactory;
```

I'd like to use junit instead of Maven because the compilation of the single test case (or class) is much faster with junit (milliseconds instead of a few seconds).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you able to run your java file?

Comment: @deadshot The test case works if I run it through Intellij

Comment: what I am asking is will you able to run java file does it working or showing the same error as above?

Comment: @deadshot I edited the question and now it shows the error